# How to combine Auto Layout constraints with contentMode property of UIView

Tags: ios, autolayout, cornerradius, contentmode

I have a `UIImageView` object configured with Auto Layout. I have created constraints so that the view keeps a constant distance to its superview. In visual format it would be like:

```
@"V:|-[imageView]-|"
@"H:|-[imageView]-|"
```

But I would also like to keep the aspect ratio of the underlying image, so I have assigned `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` to `contentMode`.

I thought everything was working well until I set the `cornerRadius` value of the associated `CALayer`:

```
self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
self.imageView.layer.maskToBounds = YES;
```

Now when the image view is resized, e.g. due to a change in orientation, the rounded corners are lost depending on the new size the view gets. The reason is that `cornerRadius` applies to the `UIImageView` (frame in dashes below), but since the underlying image is also resized to respect `contentMode` (frame in asterisks below), rounded corners are not visible anymore:

```
--------------------------
|       **********       |
|       *        *       |
|       *        *       |
|       *        *       |
|       **********       |
--------------------------
```

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 27):

like @jacob-k said, you should add to your cell subclass `layoutSubviews` , but just to add you should call `layoutIfNeeded` first.

Example:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];
  [self layoutIfNeeded];
  imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
}
```

If you won't call `layoutIfNeeded` first, then it apply all changes without your set constraints.

Comment: Thank you..working like a charm. struggling for so long.

Comment: This work for a UITableViewCell only if you attach constraints to the tableview cell and NOT to the contentView. (views can still be added to the contentView

Comment: this is the solution if you have complex constraints for all size classes in uitableviewcell

Comment: How does anyone combine this approach with constraints animation that affects size of view?

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to do it could be to subclass UIImageView and set the corner radius in `layoutSubviews`.